# Why are the frame and color fill not properly aligned vertically?

Tags: titlesec

```
%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno,fleqn]{amsbook} %
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc} % more advanced but essential here
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{mathptmx} % place after txfonts
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref} % For creating hyperlinks in cross references
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ulem} % for underlining - keep
\let\chead\undefined % un-define
\let\cfoot\undefined % un-define
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap} %
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} % define colors, color table, order important
\usepackage[flequ]{mathtools} % necessary
\usepackage[position=below,labelfont={bf},textfont=normal]{caption,subfig} % 08_03_2014 (subfig from package)
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\special{papersize=210mm,297mm} % printer choice

% ----------- lengths ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\setlength{\paperwidth}{175mm} % width of book [165mm] - set in geometry
\setlength{\textwidth}{135mm} % width of text [127mm]

\setlength{\paperheight}{235mm} % height of book [205mm]
\setlength{\topmargin}{-22mm} % clear above header [-22mm]
\setlength{\headheight}{16mm} % height of head [15mm]
\setlength{\headsep}{4mm} % between header and text [3mm]
\setlength{\textheight}{195mm} % height of text inclusive of header/footer [172]

% ------------ paragraphs --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\setlength{\parskip}{3.4pt} % gap between paragraphs [3pt]
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % indentation of paragraphs

\makeatletter % only needed in preamble
\renewcommand\small{\@setfontsize\small{10}{11}}
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{11}{13}}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{12.2}{14}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{14.4}{16}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{1.0pt}

\def\mymediumspace{\kern 0.4pt}
\def\mythickspace{\kern 0.6pt}
\def\mygraphicspace{\kern 0.75pt}
\def\comma{\kern 0.4pt}
\def\figtab{\kern 0.7pt} % layout of fig/table numbering - good 22_02_2014

% ------------------------------------- COUNTERS TO SET GLOBALLY ------------------------------------ %

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} %
\setcounter{section}{1} % was 1
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % depth in contents lists
\setcounter{equation}{2}

\setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}

\newcommand\Hrule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2.5pt}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt} %
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7pt} %

\makeatletter
\titlelabel{\thetitle\enspace}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\renewcommand\tocsection[3]{\indentlabel{\hspace{0pt}#1 \hspace{0pt}#2\hspace{6.4pt}}#3} %
\renewcommand\tocsubsection[3]{\indentlabel{\hspace{0pt}#1 \hspace{0pt}#2\hspace{6.4pt}}#3} %

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\mythickspace.\mythickspace\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\mythickspace.\mythickspace\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatother

\ChNameVar{\fontsize{20}{20}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\selectfont} % for fancy header
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{60}{90}\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont}
\ChTitleVar{\Large\bfseries\rm}
\ChRuleWidth{2.5pt}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{32mm} % 32mm
\setlength{\marginparsep}{11mm} % 7mm
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}
\setfootwidth[0pt]{head}

\newlength\widestnum
\setlength\widestnum{36pt} %


\titleformat{\section}[frame] %                                                                                               line 1
  {\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{13.6}{20}\selectfont}{}{-1pt} %                                 line 2
  {\makebox[\linewidth+2pt] % pushes fill and number to right                                     line 3
    {\colorbox{red!15} %                                                                                                                    line 4
    {\parbox{\linewidth-8pt} % -ve shortens the fill                                                          line 5
  {\parbox{\widestnum}{\hspace{7pt}\thesection} %                                                               line 6
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-\widestnum\relax} %                                                                line 7
    {\strut#1\strut}}}}} %                                                                                                              line 8

\titleformat{\subsection}[frame] %                                                                                        line 1
  {\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12.6}{18}\selectfont}{}{-1pt} %                                 line 2
  {\makebox[\linewidth+2pt] % pushes fill and number to right                                     line 3
    {\colorbox{blue!15} %                                                                                                               line 4
    {\parbox{\linewidth-8pt} % -ve shortens the fill                                                          line 5
  {\parbox{\widestnum}{\hspace{7pt}\thesubsection} %                                                        line 6
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-\widestnum\relax} %                                                                line 7
    {\strut#1\strut}}}}} %                                                                                                              line 8

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{8pt}{6pt}[0pt] %
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{8pt}{6pt}[0pt]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{8pt}{6pt}[0pt]


\begin{document}

\vspace{12pt}

\chapter{This is chapter ONE}

\section{The section frame and RED fill do not line up.}

\subsection{The subsection frame and BLUE fill do not line up.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using `amsbook` when you change *all* of its setup? Use `book` instead. And, please, avoid the Lenny chapter style, one of the worst I've ever seen.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I admit to being a novice at this. What are the benefits of changing over to book, now that I've settled things like theorems?

Answer (score 2):

This is ugly and you should be using some `tikz` way for doing stuff like this. Let me know if you are interested in using `tikz` and `titlesec`. Anyway, this should give you some idea.

Instead of using `frame` option of `titlesec`, you can use `fcolorbox`. This won't break lines and if you want breaks, use a `\parbox` inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
     {\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{13.6}{20}\selectfont}
     {}
     {1pt}%
     {\fcolorbox{black}{red}{#1}} %
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]%
     {\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{13.6}{20}\selectfont}
     {}
     {1pt}%
     {\fcolorbox{black}{blue!40}{#1}} %
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{8pt}{6pt}[0pt]

\begin{document}
  \section{The section frame and RED fill do not line up.}
  Some text
  \subsection{This is a sub section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would be interested in using \tikz and titlesec if you have the time. I would love to have more visible control.

Comment: @user24039 Do you want section numbers or not? If yes, whether they should be inside the coloured rectangle or not? Some explanation will be useful. And may be you can ask a new question with some code too.

Comment: Yes, please. and inside the frame.