# Background Color for Section Title

Tags: formatting

I have seen many answers to this question, but all of them seem very complicated and I don't understand how they work at all (copy and pasting them into my code doesn't seem to work either).

I should also add that I'm completely new to this.

All I want is a simple code that takes the default section title in LaTeX

[image]

and fills it in to become something like

[image]

This is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Look at the `titlesec` package.

Comment: e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224147.

Comment: Should it be for all section titles, or only occasionally?

Comment: For all section titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[, x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE}{\rlap{\color{Aquamarine1!92!Chartreuse1}\rule[-0.4cm]{\linewidth}{1.2cm}} \thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if the `\secnumdepth` is set to 0.

Comment: Of course, in this case `\thesection `in the code is meaningless. Anyway, even for unnumbered sections, it is easy to adapt the code to `\titleformat{name=\section,numberless]{...}`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Since this is your answer, do you want to add an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518841/background-color-in-titlesec) which is almost the same, but for the unnumbered section.

Comment: I'll do it in a moment. Thanks!

Comment: @AlanMunn: Colouring the frame is more complex than I thought. I'll look at it tomorrow (it's very late here…). Feel free to post if you have a solution